# Testing exception handling in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, exception

I have this oracle code

```
 FUNCTION get_enc_val(p_in                          IN VARCHAR2,
                        p_key                         IN VARCHAR2
                       )
   RETURN raw
   IS
      p_title_procedure_name        VARCHAR2(100) := 'get_enc_val';
      l_enc_val                     RAW(2000);
      l_mod                         PLS_INTEGER := DBMS_CRYPTO.ENCRYPT_AES128 + DBMS_CRYPTO.CHAIN_CBC + DBMS_CRYPTO.PAD_PKCS5;
      v_key                         VARCHAR2(16);

      encryption_ex Exception;
   BEGIN



      v_key                 := RPAD(SUBSTR(TRIM(p_key), 1, 16), 16, '0');
      l_enc_val             := DBMS_CRYPTO.encrypt(UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(p_in), l_mod, UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(v_key));


      RAISE encryption_ex;

      RETURN l_enc_val;

   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         service_func.log_error(p_title_package_name || '.' || p_title_procedure_name, 'Proc', NULL, SYSDATE, SQLERRM, p_in || '~' || p_key);
         RETURN 'Encryption_ERROR';
   END;
```

When I run this I get ORA-06510 Unhandled user-defined exception while it should really return the string 'Encryption_ERROR'.What gives? It goes to the Exception block, because I see the result of log_error function. Question is, isn't the Exception block supposed to HANDLE ANY exception?

I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your second RETURN statement is returning a VARCHAR2 while your function is declared to return a RAW.  You could fix that by calling UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW, i.e.

```
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS THEN
         service_func.log_error(p_title_package_name || '.' || 
                                   p_title_procedure_name, 
                                'Proc', 
                                NULL, 
                                SYSDATE, 
                                SQLERRM, 
                                p_in || '~' || p_key);
         RETURN utl_raw.cast_to_raw( 'Encryption_ERROR' );
   END;
```

If I declare two functions, one that returns a hard-coded string and one that returns a RAW, you'll see the difference (I'm removing the DBMS_CRYPTO calls and the LOG_ERROR call).  If I declare a function that returns a RAW, you get a result back (though a human would have to convert the raw back into a string to make sense of the result)

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace function throw_exception
  2    return raw
  3  is
  4    my_exception exception;
  5  begin
  6    raise my_exception;
  7  exception
  8    when others then
  9      return utl_raw.cast_to_raw( 'Foo' );
 10* end;
SQL> /

Function created.

SQL> select throw_exception
  2    from dual;

THROW_EXCEPTION
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

466F6F
```

If I just return a string, I'll get the same exception you were getting

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  create or replace function throw_exception2
  2    return raw
  3  is
  4    my_exception exception;
  5  begin
  6    raise my_exception;
  7  exception
  8    when others then
  9      return 'Foo';
 10* end;
SQL> /

Function created.

SQL> select throw_exception2
  2    from dual;
select throw_exception2
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: hex to raw conversion error
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.THROW_EXCEPTION2", line 9
ORA-06510: PL/SQL: unhandled user-defined exception
```

Of course, the other option would be to declare that the function returns a VARCHAR2.  But I would much rather have hashes and encrypted data in a RAW than a VARCHAR2 so that you never have to worry about things like character set conversion issues mangling the data.

Comment: good:) BUT utl_raw.cast_to_raw returns encoded gibberish instead of Encryption_Error....

Comment: CAST_TO_RAW will only return encoded gibberish if you pass it gibberish. You can always transform it back. But the best option is to raise the error to the caller and not try to pass back a magic value. If you MUST pass back a magic value, perhaps NULL is better.

Comment: @gnomixa - Like I said, you'd have to utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2 for a human to make sense of the magic value.  If you want the function to return a RAW, the results by definition will not be human-readable.  You can have the function return a VARCHAR2 but then the encrypted data returned will also be a VARCHAR2 and thus subject to character set conversion issues.  This is one of the reason's that Gary's point about not using magic values is a good one.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are sure that `service_func.log_error(...);` is not raising the error, the error must be thrown by the calling procedure/function.

And here's something that raises the same error.

```
create or replace function abc return raw is
begin
    return 'Encryption_ERROR';
end;
/

declare
     r raw(50);
begin
     r := abc;
end;
/
```

Comment: Yes I am. All checked. All it does it makes an entry to the error table.